# How do I troubleshoot Microsoft.Windows.Storage.StorageException:The remote name could not be resolved

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I am troubleshooting why a particular computer started getting this exception yesterday with code it regularly runs.

I created the following test to reproduce the problem

```
        var account =
            CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={accountName};" +
                $"AccountKey={accountKey}");
        var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var conref = client.GetContainerReference(containerRef);
                var blobref = conref.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        blobref.DownloadToFile(fullDownloadName, FileMode.Create);
```

On a good pc running windows 2012 Server Release 2 ,the file downloads
On the bad pc running windows 8.1 only a zero length empty file creates

I rebooted the bad PC.
What else can I try?

both pcs have internet access.

Console.WriteLine($"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={accountName};" + $"AccountKey={accountKey}")

looks the same on both pcs.

The test console app references WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.2

I am installing the console app via file copy.
Here are the files
[image: files]

[Update]

I am trying to install the client tools from  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

I have a this site can't be reached error.

[image: this site can't be reached error]

Comment: Can you verify that the cloud storage connection string `$"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={accountName};" +
                $"AccountKey={accountKey}"` gets resolved right?

Comment: is there a way to ping a storage account?

Comment: You can either assign the same string to a variable and debug it or depending on the application type you can use something like Console.WriteLine($"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={accountName};" +
                $"AccountKey={accountKey}")

Comment: Thank you @MartinBrandl  I updated the question.

Comment: @KirstenGreed You cannot ping a storage account endpoint. Have you tried any other operations, such as listing containers for your storage account, or listing blobs within a specific container? Have you double-checked that the SDK versions are the same on both machines?

Comment: @DavidMakogon  How do I do that? I am unfamiliar with what the SDK is. I updated the question to show the reference the code is using.

Comment: @KirstenGreed - You're already using the SDK (all of the `CloudStorageAccount` stuff, along with the cloud storage client you're creating, etc.). And to make that code work, you had to install the SDK locally on your development machine. And it's important that you're using the same version of the SDK on each machine, to get the most consistent results.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sv0YttC20cU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed the local DNS to 1.1.1.1
then ran IPConfig /flushdns
then my test started working.

However having the DNS server not be the domain server was problematic ( access errors )

So then we changed the local DNS back to the domain server and set the secondary DNS to 1.1.1.1

Rebooted the domain server and the box

Comment: https://redmondmag.com/articles/2004/05/01/10-dns-errors-that-will-kill-your-network.aspx